# SSH to private instances from bastion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently connected to my bastion server:

```
Name-MacBook-Pro:.ssh name$ sudo ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@public-dns
Last login: Fri Oct 26 17:20:42 2018 from nat-000-000-000-000.central.domain.edu

   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
  ___|\___|___|
```

And I'm trying to connect to my AppServer instance from within it, which is a private instance

```
[ec2-user@public_bastion_ip ~]$ ssh ec2-user@private_ip_of_app_server          
ssh: connect to host private_ip port 22: Connection timed out
```

Do I have to work with some security features opening port 22?

Comment: The private instance needs to allow inbound port 22 from the bastion. You do this by configuring a Security Group on the private instance(s).

Answer (score 1):

Check if the security group you are using on the private server has port 22 opened.  (It should.)  If not, add it.  Then try `ssh` again.

```
AWS Console->EC2 service->Running Instances->select your instance in the "Filter by tags and attributes or search by keyword"
```

Now, scroll to far right, look for `Security Group`, and click it.
Now go `Actions->Inbound Rules` and see if port 22 is open.  If not, add it.